# Как int конвертировать в DateTime в C#?

Tags: c#

У меня есть дата (начало периода) и количество дней (в виде int). Мне нужно прибавить количество дней к началу периода. Например: есть дата (2011-02-04), и есть количество дней(305). Нужно, что бы получилась дата(конец периода). Реально ли это? Если да, то как это можно сделать? Заранее всем спасибо)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.adddays

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу

```
Data.Value.AddDays(305);
```